# how to create public SQL server

Tags: windows, sql-server, database, sql, sql-server-2014

I installed sql server on my computer.

I can work with it as localserver.

But i want to it to be a public server.

I followed lot of tutorials but it's still don't work(I can't connect the server from outer computer).

I'am using java, wotking with `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc` library.

and when i try to connect the server with my ip adress it's throws exception:

```
The TCP/IP connection to the host 31.168.22.40, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".``
```

although it's opened - I opend it in my router and in all of my firewalls(eset and windows firewalls), I also tried some port test's in they all said it's ok:

http://postimg.org/image/ehfye5pq1/

I configure it at SQL Server Configuration Manager at it should be(TCP enabled on 1433 port).

I tried to connect it with managment studio and it's didn't work with

> provider: SQL Network Interface, error 26

Can someone help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

there are two thinks to configure for opening SqlServer to the wild:

In configuration manager:
[image]

And in SSMS:
[image]

Sorry my server is in french...

Comment: This two options are both checked and active, and it's still don't work.